# BLAST inconsistent results

Tags: bioinformatics, phylogeny, blast, ncbi

I am new to bioinformatics and have recently started using local version of BLAST. I'm trying to get consistent results with my reference, which is rpl26 gene from Alexandrium tamarense. Depending whether I use local or online versions of blastn, I get different results.
[image: Here are my online blast parameters]

As expected, I get 500 hits from that. However, when i try:

```
/home/jedrzej/ncbi-blast-2.10.0+/bin/blastn -task blastn -query $query_path -db $db_path -out $out_name -outfmt "6 qseqid sseqid pident length mismatch qstart qend sstart send evalue bitscore sscinames scomnames sblastnames sskingdoms stitle"
```

I get 511 hits. I suspected the parameters differ from the online version, so I've also tried:

```
/home/jedrzej/ncbi-blast-2.10.0+/bin/blastn -task blastn -query $query_path -db $db_path -out $out_name -outfmt "6 qseqid sseqid pident length mismatch qstart qend sstart send evalue bitscore sscinames scomnames sblastnames sskingdoms stitle" -word_size 11 -gapopen 5 -gapextend 2 -penalty -3 -reward 2
```

But the result was the same. Max_target_seqs in blastn defaults to 500, so I suppose there shouldn't be more than 500 hits.

As a side note, I also tried modifying max_target_seqs to 20000:

```
/home/jedrzej/ncbi-blast-2.10.0+/bin/blastn -task blastn -query $query_path -db $db_path -out $out_name -outfmt "6 qseqid sseqid pident length mismatch qstart qend sstart send evalue bitscore sscinames scomnames sblastnames sskingdoms stitle" -max_target_seqs 20000
```

But that as well differs from the results of online BLAST, when I increase max target sequences to 20000. I get 1980 (local) vs 1950 (online) hits.

Why do I get different results? Is that a database problem?

Comment: Yes, your problem is likely database-related. Study the specification and date of release available in the Readme file on the ftp server. Also, the defaults are [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK279684/#appendices.Options_for_the_commandline_a).

Comment: That may be in terms of varying number of results, but I still don't understand why does the script return 511 results instead of the default 500.